Pinescript: How to detect a crossover and crossunder of plotted lines based of pivots support and resistance plotted by array and map function?
enter image description here
Please help guys I have not found any solution yet on how to use a ta.crossover(close,????) to detect a candle breakout off a support or resistance from these plotted lines. Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks guys. This is a priceaction concept of trading, any suggestion are very much appreciated.
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

tt1 = "Maximum number of crossover/crossunder. Each time price crosses support/resistance line, it is counted as a cross and when such crosses reaches 'Max crossover/crossunder' the support/resistance line is removed"

//@version=5
indicator('Map example [EDITED]', overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)
oc = input.int(title = 'Open & Close Pip Gap', defval = 2, minval = 1)
lb = input.int(title = 'Left bars', defval = 1, minval = 1)
rb = input.int(title = 'Right bars', defval = 1, minval = 1)
max_cross_cnt = input.int(title = 'Max crossover/crossunder', defval = 2, minval = 1, maxval = 10, tooltip = tt1)
cross_cnt_as_width = input.bool(title = 'Set line width based on cross count', defval = true)
start_date = input.time(timestamp("07 Nov 2024 21:30:00"))

var map_sr_cross = map.new<int, int>()
var map_sr_type = map.new<int, string>()

var color_map = map.new<string, color>()
var style_map = map.new<string, string>()

if bar_index == 0
    color_map.put("S", color.orange)
    color_map.put("R", color.orange)
    style_map.put("S", line.style_solid)
    style_map.put("R", line.style_solid)
    style_map.put("StR", line.style_dashed)
    style_map.put("RtS", line.style_dashed)

//@function returns color
method get(map<string, color> clr, string key) => clr.get(key)
//@function returns line style
method get(map<string, string> style, string key) => style.get(key)
//@function Returns count of price crosses from a map
method count(map<int, int> cnt, int key) => cnt.get(key)
//@function increments cross count in a map
method increment(map<int, int> cnt, int key) => cnt.put(key, cnt.get(key) + 1)
//@function Returns type S=support, R=reistance from a map.
method get(map <int, string> types, int key) => types.get(key)
//@function sets type S=support, R=reistance in a map
method set(map <int, string> types, int key, string val ) => types.put(key, val)
//@function deletes a map element
method delete(map<int, int> lines, int key) => lines.remove(key)
method delete(map<int, string> lines, int key) => lines.remove(key)
//@function returns crossover/crossunder if price crosses swing point
method state(float pp) => (close > pp and open+(oc/10) < pp) ? 'Crossover' : (close < pp and open-(oc/10) > pp) ? 'Crossunder' : na
//@function manipulate support/resistance lines based on price action
method price_action(array<line> lines) =>
    size = lines.size()
    if(size > 0)
        for i = size - 1 to 0 
            price_point = line.get_y1(lines.get(i))
            state = price_point.state()
            if(not na(state))
                bar_id = line.get_x1(lines.get(i))
                if(map_sr_cross.count(bar_id) + 1 >= max_cross_cnt)
                    line.delete(lines.get(i))
                    map_sr_cross.delete(i)
                    map_sr_type.delete(i)
                if(map_sr_cross.count(bar_id) + 1 < max_cross_cnt)
                    this_sr_type = map_sr_type.get(bar_id)
                    map_sr_type.set(bar_id, this_sr_type == 'R' ? 'S' : 'R')
                    style_key = this_sr_type + 't' + (this_sr_type == 'R' ? 'S' : 'R')
                    map_sr_cross.increment(bar_id)
                    line.set_style(lines.get(i), style_map.get(style_key))
                    line.set_color(lines.get(i), color_map.get(this_sr_type == 'R' ? 'S' : 'R'))
                    line.set_width(lines.get(i), cross_cnt_as_width ? map_sr_cross.count(bar_id) : 1)
                    

//main code
ph = ta.pivothigh(close, lb, rb)
pl = ta.pivotlow(close, lb, rb)

if(ph and time >= start_date)
    line.new(bar_index-rb, close[rb], bar_index, close[rb], color = color_map.get('R'),  style = style_map.get('R'), extend = extend.right)
    map_sr_cross.put(bar_index-rb, 0)
    map_sr_type.set(bar_index-rb, 'R')
    // map_sr_type.put(bar_index-rb, 'R')

if(pl and time >= start_date)
    line.new(bar_index-rb, close[rb], bar_index, close[rb], color = color_map.get('S'),  style = style_map.get('S'), extend = extend.right)
    map_sr_cross.put(bar_index-rb, 0)
    map_sr_type.set(bar_index-rb, 'S')
    // map_sr_type.put(bar_index-rb, 'S')

//manipulate support/resistance lines based on price action
line.all.price_action()


When you have an array, you need to write your custom cross function.
Essentially, you want to loop over all elements in your array and check one by one if the price crossed it.
Once you find a cross, you can take any action you want (delete line, alert etc.).
Here is a simple example:
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_crossover(p_arr) =>
    is_crossed = false
    len = array.size(p_arr)

    if (len > 0)
        for i = 0 to len - 1
            support_price = array.get(p_arr, i)

            if ((open < support_price) and (high > support_price))      // Candle opened below the support and crossed it
                is_crossed := true

    is_crossed

arr_support = array.from(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)

is_support_crossed = f_crossover(arr_support)

plot(close)


i will try your solution tonight. thanks.
btw, Is it possible to do a ta.crossover the plotted lines? like ta.crossover(close, orange solid/dashed line)?

No. But if you are plotting something, you already know its value so you can use that.

Thank you for your help. Can I know how I can get the values of the plotted lines from my script above so I can use that value for a ta.crossover(close,value) ? sorry I am new to pinescript, I adjusted these codes from an indicator from open published on tv. greatly appreciated if you can help

kindly help, very much appreciated. thanks @vitruvius

You can use line.get_y2() or line.get_price() functions to get the price.

Thank you.
breakout = ta.crossover(close, line.get_y1("id"))
Based on the script I couldnt figure out the "id" for the line.get_y2("id") as the "id" I believe need to refer to does exist inside a function.
Kindly help, appreciate very much

really appreciate your help brother @vitruvius
